# r use apply to update a data-frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have the following dataframe 'adjustedShiftLengths':

```
                          PositionCDF Avg_shift_len Avg_shift_median  Adjusted_avg_shift_len
1          Emergency Medicine - Nurse             6                6       0                      
2                               Nurse             6                6       0               
3              Nurse - Intensive Care             6                6       0
```

I want to update the 'Adjusted_avg_shift_len' in this dataframe for each row by applying a function. Basically the new value to be updated in 'Adjusted_avg_shift_len' should be lets say the result of calling another function getAdjustedShiftLengths(Avg_shift_len)

This is what i have so far:

```
updateAdjustedValues <- function (valueToBeRounded, row) {
  adjustedShiftLengths$Adjusted_avg_shift_len[row] <- adjustShiftLength(valueToBeRounded)
}
```

I am not sure how to pass in the 'row' value to the apply function (i.e the argument to function updateAdjustedValues)

```
> apply(adjustedShiftLengths, 1, updateAdjustedValues(adjustedShiftLengths$Avg_shift_len,row ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass a `row` argument to `apply`; instead, `apply` will pass a row as the first argument to the function it is calling.

Your code should look like this:

```r
adjustedShiftLengths['Adjusted_avg_shift_len'] <- apply(adjustedShiftLengths, 1, updateAdjustedValues)
```

But then you would need to adjust your function `updateAdjustedValues`

```r
updateAdjustedValues <- function (row) {
    getAdjustedShiftLengths(row['Avg_shift_len'])
}
```

Another approach would be to use `transform`, which I think to be more suitable to your case.

```r
transform(adjustedShiftLengths, Adjusted_avg_shift_len=getAdjustedShiftLengths(Avg_shift_len))
```

When using `transform`, you can access the columns directly by their names, i.e., you are in the dataframe's scope. Accordingly, one possible way to use `transform` is

```r
df <- transform(df, ExistingColumn1 = ExistingColumn1 ^ 2, ExistingColumn2 = someFunction(ExistingColumn2), NewColumn = ExistingColumn1 + ExistingColumn2)
```

Example

```r
sq <- function(x) x^2
df <- iris
df <- transform(iris, Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length * 1000, Sepal.Width = sq(Sepal.Width), Sepal.Weirdo = Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)
```

In this example, a new variable (column) named `Sepal.Weirdo` will be created, but its values will be according to the existing `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` values, not the values after `transform`ing the `df`.

Note: if you have a large data set, you may consider working with [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But in case i use apply, how would i reference this implicit row number within updateAdjustedValues () so that it can be passed as an argument  to the 'adjustShiftLength' function?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that. If you just want to iterate over the rows numbers, do something like `for (i in in 1:nrow(adjustedShiftLengths))`. The thing is, you don't need to do that. Apply will pick up every row for you and pass it as an argument. For me, in your particular case, it makes more sense to use `transform`.

Comment: thanks for the guidance!  I have already implemented using the for loop and have this working. will look into apply or transform to see if i can implement it with that too

Comment: @Rookie I'm glad it helps. I added an example about `transform`. Let me know if that is not clear.